# Number of ways to cut a cuboid

Tags: combinations, volume

There is a cuboid of size b * b * a which needs to be cut into '2a' smaller cuboid of size (b/2) * (b/2) * 2. How many different ways are there to cut the bigger cuboid to achieve the required smaller cuboid?

Comment: Hello!  This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I have no idea how to approach such problem. Though I have solved this somewhat similar problem on spoj. http://www.spoj.com/problems/BC/